# Cannot import wsdl When asmx added Localy(XMLFile)

Tags: xml, wcf, asmx

I have old wcf Webservice and for Network problems I decide to save Service WSDL in XML File and Call Localy in my AspCore Project For Test Functions But I have This Error:

Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://est']/wsdl:binding[@name='EstelamPortBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://est']/wsdl:service[@name='Estelam']/wsdl:port[@name='EstelamPort']
Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://est']/wsdl:portType[@name='EstelamPort']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://est']/wsdl:binding[@name='EstelamPortBinding']
Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://est' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://est']/wsdl:portType[@name='EstelamPort']

Notic:I Chang location to Locally Address in my XML

Answer (score 0):

Although you can call WCF services in .net core, it is subject to some restrictions. The WCF client in .net core only supports four bindings: BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding, and there are not many security features in .net Core.

About core's support for WCF, you can refer to this link:

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf